# pycharm issue non project file

Tags: pycharm

My file that I wrote highlight as non project file. how can I do? how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does this change anything: right click > mark as > source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution From @ValentinKuhn didn't work for me. I had to go to:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Project Structure
4. Add my project folder to the source